# Can the Universe reach Equilibrium using Dark Matter and Dark Energy

Tags: cosmology, entropy, space-expansion, universe

As I was studying dark energy, dark matter and The Expansion, I thought that if there was enough Dark Matter to stop the Expansion, and enough Dark Energy to make sure it does not end in a big crunch, could the universe maintain its Entropy and Energy? and if not, is there any other way to create Entropy to make sure the Universe does not die out?

Comment: This was basically the premise of Einstein's cosmological constant needed for a static universe.

Comment: @Triatticus Oh... But I don't think lambda and Dark Energy are the same